# MFC: How do you handle putting up a right drag-and-drop context menu?

Tags: winapi, drag-and-drop, mfc

I have a drop target (`CTreeView`) that accepts `CF_HDROP`.  When I drag/drop using left mouse button, it works as expected (with Move/Copy option via shift/ctrl keys), when I do a drag/drop using the right button, it treats it the same as the left, no context menu.  I've tried dragging from the desktop to the tree view (as well as internally from a list view to the tree view).

I am aware of the method of showing a context menu when the program internally handles the process of checking when the right button down, track when dragging when mouse moves, and releasing button to do drop.  But since this is a drop-target from anything (using `OnDrop()`), how do I handle getting the context menu to show for the option to either copy or move?

Thanks!!

Comment: The drop target always controls the drop operation in Windows, and this includes showing a menu if desired. It's up to you to build the menu and show it.

Comment: But how do I know it's a right click drop and not a left click?  There isn't any parameters that give that information.  `OnDrop(COleDataObject* pdataobject, DROPEFFECT dropeffect, CPoint point)`   ?

Comment: In `OnDragEnter`, test if the right button is down with `GetKeyState(VK_RBUTTON)` and save a flag that you can check in `OnDrop`. Note also it's recommended to use `OnDropEx` rather than `OnDrop` to support a right-drag menu (because it tells you which actions are allowed).

Comment: Ok, didn't think I'd have to save the state, but I guess so.  I see you can get it from the dwkeystate parameter: `m_RightButtonDrop=((dwkeystate & (MK_RBUTTON|MK_LBUTTON))==MK_RBUTTON);`

Comment: You can still get mouse button statue (`grfKeyState`) in [`IDropTarget::Drop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleidl/nf-oleidl-idroptarget-drop) of Win32. However, there is no key state in MFC API [`OnDrop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/coledroptarget-class?view=vs-2019#ondrop). So you may check left button or right button is pressed in [`OnDragEnter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/coledroptarget-class?view=vs-2019#ondragenter) and save a flag as @JonathanPotter pointed out.

Comment: As for drop context menu you can refer to shell document: [Creating Drag-and-Drop Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers#creating-drag-and-drop-handlers). "*When a user right-clicks a Shell object to drag an object, a shortcut menu is displayed when the user attempts to drop the object.*"